# How can I get a rhandsontable to react to changes in input values and to changes in itself?

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

So I want to have a table of values in an rHOT that update whenever 
1) the underlying data is updated via reactive input 
AND
 2) whenever you update the values in the rHOT table.

The code below manages to refresh the real avgs/cums table when the input$ changes.
Then I can type new values into the rHOT table' avgs and the cums will update.

But I want to refresh the rHOT table's values all over again when you change the input$ again, and still be receptive to changes in its own Avg row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)

accdntprd<-1:5
StatData<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(100, 150, 175, 180, 200, 110, 
                                 168, 192, 205, 210, 115, 169,
                                 202, 200, 100, 125, 185, 100, 
                                 120, 130, 150, 180, 190, 200, 210), 
                               nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE))
StatData<-as.data.frame(cbind(accdntprd,StatData[1:5,]))


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Shiny"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs", menuItem("Blocks", tabName = "Blocks"))),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(

    tabItem("Blocks",
            fluidRow(box(width=12
                         ,div(tableOutput("DFs"))
                         ,div(rHandsontableOutput("rTable"))      
            )),
            fluidRow(width=12,
                     box(radioButtons("SelAvgMeth", "averaging", choices= c("straight", "trim"), selected = "straight"))     
            )
    )
  ))
)

server<-function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(
    input$SelAvgMeth, {

      rTable_content <<- reactive({

        t<-ifelse(input$SelAvgMeth=="trim",1, 0)
        Avgs<-t(sapply((2:5),function(i){mean(StatData[, i+1]/StatData[, i], trim = t/4)}))

        Avgs<-rev(Avgs)
        Cums<-cumprod(Avgs)
        DF<-t(as.data.frame(cbind(rev(Avgs), rev(Cums))))
        DF<-data.frame(DF)
        rownames(DF)<-c("Avgs", "Cums")
        return(DF)

      })

      output$DFs<-renderTable({
        rTable_content()
      }, digits = 3, spacing = "xs", rownames = TRUE)

    })   


  MyChanges <- reactive({

    if(is.null(input$rTable)|(identical(rTable_content(),input$rTable))){
      return(rTable_content())
    } else {
      selDF<- as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$rTable)) 
      selDF[2,]<-rev(cumprod(rev(as.numeric(selDF[1,]))))
      rownames(selDF)<-c("Avgs", "Cums")
      return(selDF)
    } 
  })
  output$rTable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(MyChanges())%>% hot_cols(format = "0.000")
  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I know the observe event is not really necessary, but let's leave it there in case I want to control for other inputs.

Forgive me if I asked this wrong. The code is reproducible.

**How it should work in pictures:**

1. [Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20OLy.jpg)
2. [Select Trim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do4oJ.jpg)

   3.
   [Accept rHOT changes in top row and auto calculate bottom row. No
   changes to StatData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwPYj.jpg)

Comment: My apologies, I'm still a bit confused. It looks like your `rTable_content` is updated based on your original `StatData` information every time you change your `input$SelAvgMeth` radiobutton. So if you changed your rHOT values, how should `rTable_content` recalculate? Does it still need the original values from `StatData`? If it does, won't the results always be different than a changed rHOT table? Perhaps a specific example of what `rTable_content` should do after your rHOT table changes might be helpful.

Comment: When rTable_content changes, the rhot table should change with it. This can be accomplished by setting myChanges to the rtable_content.  Then the rhot table can have user input changes and the rHOT table should show the changes by the user. StatData and the rHOT should be independent, but rHOT should reset whenever StatData changes. I will add screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the additional details.

I might create separate `reactiveValues` to store your tables and give you more flexibility.

The part I'm still unclear on is what should happen if the radio button is selected after the rHOT table has changed. Right now, it just sets both tables back based on original data.

See if this has the behavior you were looking for.

```
server<-function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(table1 = NULL,
                       table2 = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$SelAvgMeth,{
    t <- ifelse(input$SelAvgMeth == "trim", 1, 0)
    Avgs<-t(sapply((2:5),function(i){mean(StatData[, i+1]/StatData[, i], trim = t/4)}))
    Avgs<-rev(Avgs)
    Cums<-cumprod(Avgs)
    DF<-t(as.data.frame(cbind(rev(Avgs), rev(Cums))))
    DF<-data.frame(DF)
    rownames(DF)<-c("Avgs", "Cums")
    rv$table1<-rv$table2<-DF
  })

  output$DFs<-renderTable({
    rv$table1
  }, digits = 3, spacing = "xs", rownames = TRUE)

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$rTable)){
      selDF<- as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$rTable)) 
      selDF[2,]<-rev(cumprod(rev(as.numeric(selDF[1,]))))
      rownames(selDF)<-c("Avgs", "Cums")
      rv$table2 <- selDF
    } 
  })

  output$rTable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(rv$table2) %>%
      hot_cols(format = "0.000")
  })

}
```

Comment: You did it! That is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why I was making it more complicated than it was. Once the radio button changes, I do want both tables updated --undoing any changes i made in the rhot. But allowing me to update the rhot based on the refreshed values.  Thank you so much!